# creating jhipster-spring boot project war file error

Tags: docker, spring-boot, war, jhipster

I have an jhipster-spring boot application which is running docker. I want to create war file. I found some commands here:
`https://jhipster.github.io/production/`

When I type `./mvnw -Pdev package` .I am typing this command in intellij terminal. I am getting this error:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/23082073/

I have no idea what is it because normally my app is running correcty. What I need for creating war? Should I connect database? There is no more info in above link.

Thanks

Comment: You should also provide the output of `yo jhipster:info`. Also looking at the spring boot version, it seems you're using an old version of JHipster, you should consider upgrading. Also to build a production war, you should run `.mvnw -Pprod package`

Answer (score 0):

from the logs that you pasted, it looks an error from spring and hibernate. check if the connections to database are working, check if your database is setup correctly as in the logs found this

Wrong column type in FRAUD.PUBLIC.MODEL_WEIGHT for column weight. Found: double, expected: real

after that use the command ./mvnw -Pprod package to generate the WAR file.

Hope this helps.